# printf returning a segmentation fault in ASM

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64

I'm trying to learn how to change the heap section so I wrote the following code:

```
.section .data
  str1:       .string "ESTE EH UM TESTE\n"
  str2:       .string "%d\n"
  str3:       .string "%p\n"
  HEAP_START: .quad 0
  HEAP_END:   .quad 0

.section .text
.globl main

startAlocator:
  pushq %rbp
  movq %rsp, %rbp

  movq $12, %rax
  movq $0, %rdi
  syscall
  movq %rax, HEAP_START
  movq %rax, HEAP_END

  pop %rbp
  ret

main:
  pushq %rbp
  movq  %rsp, %rbp
  subq  $16, %rsp

  movq  $0, -16(%rbp)

  call startAlocator

# Print HEAP_START
  movq HEAP_START, %rsi
  mov $str3, %rdi
  call printf

# Alloc some bytes
  movq $12, %rax
  movq HEAP_END, %rdi
  addq $2, %rdi
  syscall
  movq %rax, HEAP_END

# Print HEAD_END
  movq HEAP_END, %rsi
  mov $str3, %rdi
  call printf

# Restore brk
  movq $12, %rax
  movq HEAP_START, %rdi
  syscall
  movq %rax, HEAP_END

# Print HEAD_END
  movq HEAP_END, %rsi
  mov $str3, %rdi
  call printf

# End the program
  movq  $60, %rax  #Finaliza programa
  syscall
```

But, in the last call of printf I always got a segmentation fault.

I tried to run the code using gdb to see if there was any problem with de registers, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: segfault on what instruction?  GDB will definitely tell you that; even if that didn't help *you* see the problem, it's usually very helpful to the experts you're asking.  Also, what does it output before the crash, since you said it's only the *last* call of printf that segfaults?  What does `strace ./a.out` show for system calls you're making?

Comment: The segfault is exactly at the last "call printf"
Output:

0x1494000

0x1494002

segmentation fault

Comment: `printf` (and libc in general) itself is using `brk` you can not just restore the initial break and expect stuff to not break (pun intended, sorry :))

Comment: So, how can I restore the ```brk``` ? (sorry, I'm still new learning about)

Comment: You can not if libc has done something in the meantime. You can check that whenever you adjust the break it's still the same you last set. If not, then you must not set it lower than the value libc set. Really you should just use `malloc` family if you are using libc anyway. Alternatively manage memory using `mmap`.

Comment: Ok, so I have to be careful. Sadly I can't use ```malloc``` since it's an academic work and that is one of the requirements.  Thank you Jester.

Comment: As a side effect, note that you do not own the whole range of memory. You should be keeping a list of blocks you actually allocated with start and end addresses and only use those ranges. When it comes to freeing stuff you can only free the last one (if that's still the break).

Comment: Surely you don't mean that the `call printf` instruction itself segfaults?  Because it won't unless you broke the stack, not the heap.  In case you're asking for debugging help in the future, a useful answer to my question would have been to copy/paste from GDB showing disassembly of the instructions around the one that faulted, along with the symbol name GCC shows as the current function in libc where the segfault happened.

Comment: You're exiting anyway, there's no need to free memory before doing that.  But if you really want to ask the kernel for memory you can free even after libc makes other allocations, use `mmap(MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS)`.  That interface works more like `malloc`, returning a pointer to a page or range of pages at a randomized address, and each allocation can be freed again separately with `munmap`.  (Unlike malloc/free, you have to know the length.)